# Category of finitely presented $R$-algebras cartesian closed?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, category-theory, monoidal-categories

On page 26 of [these notes](http://www.fuw.edu.pl/~kostecki/sdg.pdf), in the paragraph between formulas $(63)$ and $(64)$, the author says the category of finitely presented $R$-algebras is cartesian closed. I thought this category was symmetric monoidal closed with the tensor product given by the normal tensor product of $R$-algebras. Is the subcategory of finitely presented objects really cartesian closed? What's going on?

Answer (score 5):

The category of $R$-*modules* is monoidal closed with respect to the tensor product over $R$, but the category of $R$-algebras is not (indeed, $\otimes_R$ is just the coproduct of $R$-algebras, and so it does not distribute over coproducts, as it would have to to have a right adjoint).  However, it is not true either that the category of finitely presented $R$-algebras is cartesian closed, and I don't know why those notes claim it is.  If it were, products would have to distribute over coproducts, but this is clearly false (for instance, $R\times (R\otimes_R R)=R\times R$ is not isomorphic to $(R\times R)\otimes_R (R\times R)=R^4$).

(In fact, the category of (finitely presented) $R$-algebras admits no closed monoidal structure; I give one way to prove this in my comments on [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/208375/a-cosmos-where-coproduct-injections-are-not-monic).)

Comment: If anything, it seems more likely that the _opposite_ of the category of "very small" $R$-algebras is cartesian closed. For instance, the formal dual of $R [x] / (x^2)$ is exponentiable, if I recall correctly.

Comment: Yes, perhaps something like that is what was meant.  I still don't think the opposite category of finitely presented algebras is cartesian closed, though (that would mean there is a finite type affine scheme that is the "space of maps" $\mathbb{A}^1\to\mathbb{A}^1$, which certainly doesn't seem right.)

Comment: Indeed. A more likely candidate would be something like the opposite of the category of finite $R$-algebras, perhaps.